# How can I keep a already existing home folder in SUSE

Tags: system-installation, opensuse, home

I am swiching from Ubuntu to OpenSUSE on my system. And I have two disk on my system in wich is used for home and root. And during the partion setup, the installer prefers to use my largest disk and ignore my smallest disk (for root, home, and swap). So I try to set up the partitions (expert partitions) and try to make the installer recognize my second disk (/dev/sdb1) as my home mount disk. But the installer will either want to reformat my hard disk and delete everything or when I tell the installer not to format, the system will say that a partition does not exist. The KDE partition program recognises the disk but not the installer.

So how can I keep my home folder and my stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do it post installation:

1. Install OpenSUSE without a home partition. And if possible without users other than root.
2. Once installed, edit `/etc/fstab` to mount `/dev/sdb1` at `/home`.
3. Mount your new `/home`. Ex: `mount /home`
4. Get the user IDs (Uid) and group IDs (Gid) of the user(s) you have home directories for. Ex: `stat /home/someuser`
5. Create those user(s) with the same Uids and Gids, that way they'll have access to the files.

That's it.